# Clang Error "stddef.h file not found"?

Tags: 13.10, c, compiler, clang

After upgrading to Saucy, Clang now gives me the error message:

```
clang -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -ggdb -O0 5.1.c -o 5.1
In file included from 5.1.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:33:11: fatal error: 'stddef.h' file not found
# include <stddef.h>
          ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [5.1] Error 1
```

BTW the header I included was `stdio.h` not `stddef.h` but I am assuming that `stdio.h` references or `#includes` `stddef.h`

Answer (score 5):

You are missing header files. Their are 2 notable links related to this: [launchpad notice](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-toolchain-3.2/+bug/1196215) and [debian bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=705957). You can fix this by removing clang and install the 3.3 version with

```
sudo apt-get remove clang
sudo apt-get install clang-3.3
```